# Windows 10 not found by grub

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I had Ubuntu 14? and used the live CD to install 18.04 over the top. I also have windows 10.
Grub no longer sees windows (grub customizer at least). I have used boot-repair and this is the pastebin output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TfGDXbFyCj/

Can someone help me access windows again?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please read the article you posted around line number 1000.

Comment: Thank you @sadaharu I have read around line number 1000. What in particular should I be reading? I believe it describes the recommended repair process that I selected?
`The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to fix customized files) and reinstall the grub2 of sda8 into the MBR of sda.   
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because: no-win-efi 
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot    
   
Quantity of real Windows: 1
apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of sda8
grub-pc available`

Comment: Yes, it should look better the MBR has the GRUB bootloader. Or you can change all reinstalling everything into UEFI somehow (takes a long time to do). This Q&A would help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix